# Extract values stored in diagonal elements with the rowid as an input in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, indexing, excel-formula, match

Let's say we have the following matrix, and we want to populate `C2` by extracting the values stored in diagonal cells for the ROW Labels and COLUMN Headers matching the value in `C1`.

**Matrix:**

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2416 | 6136 | 13519 | 5298 | 1333 |
| 2 | 459 | 2416 | 5225 | 12043 | 3292 |
| 3 | 785 | 1276 | 1319 | 3188 | 14798 |
| 4 | 605 | 816 | 689 | 1539 | 4529 |
| 5 | 205 | 221 | 152 | 301 | 459 |

**Desired result**

```
C1  C2
2   2416
5   459
```

I have tried using `MATCH()` and `INDEX()` function but could not get the desired result.

**Note:** In case the matrix is stored in another sheet in a table format and I want to use `INDIRECT()` function to read the values.

Comment: What do you mean by "diagonal cells for the rowid". How is 2416 calculated?

Comment: sorry, i had uploaded the matrix incorrectly

Comment: You don't need INDIRECT to link to a different sheet. Just add the sheet name in front of the range: `'Sheet1'!B2:F6` if you really need to use indirect, show better how you want to use that. Cell input?

Comment: And for tables you can directly reference the table name, instead of the sheet. Regardless you should post more details of how you expect it to work with what details. You have a perfect solution, for a poor question.

Comment: @P.b I am sure I have followed all guidelines on how to post a question. Being an expert in the tool you could suggest on how to improve this question not label it as "poor".

Comment: If you want it to involve INDIRECT, please explain how you see that. A cell input? Give two examples of ranges (/tables) and how you expect the different input to behave on the output. Just like you shown `C1` & `C2` and their expected output. Other than the indirect part your question would be very well.

Comment: It also would've helped if you shared your attempt(s). We could've seen the range or table reference from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>INDEX()</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(H2,$B$1:$F$1,0))
```

---

Or, <kbd>SUM()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=SUM((H2=$B$1:$F$1)*(H2=$A$2:$A$6)*$B$2:$F$6)
```

---

Or, using <kbd>FILTER()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=FILTER(FILTER($B$2:$F$6,H2=$A$2:$A$6),H2=$B$1:$F$1)
```

---

Or, using <kbd>MAP()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=MAP(H2:H3,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(FILTER(B2:F6,x=A2:A6),x=B1:F1)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(H2,$B$1:$F$1,FILTER($B$2:$F$6,H2=$A$2:$A$6))
```

---

[image]

---

Assumptions based on OP's comments:

> *This formula: =XLOOKUP(H2,$B$1:$F$1,FILTER($B$2:$F$6,H2=$A$2:$A$6))*
> *and the other formulas don't seem to work if the matrix is stored in*
> *another sheet and we are using indirect function to read it.*

---

Since I am not sure for what reason you are using the <kbd>INDIRECT()</kbd> function, as it is not clear and OP doesnt seems properly explained, I tried few ways which I have commented below, just assuming if you are using <kbd>INDIRECT()</kbd> to reference the SheetTab, then you could try.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, INDIRECT(C1&"!A1:F6"),
     φ, DROP(TAKE(α,,1),1),
     δ, DROP(TAKE(α,1),,1),
     Ω, DROP(α,1,1),
     MAP(A2:A3,LAMBDA(m,FILTER(FILTER(Ω,m=φ),m=δ))))
```

---

Also what I see clearly <kbd>INDIRECT()</kbd> is not required, but yes if you have more than one sheets and want to toggle sheets to different output, then its required however in modern excel there are few functions when on clubbing those you can bring down an array of data combined and then do your manipulations with the data. But still its not clear.

One way:

[image]

---

Another way suggested by @P.b Sir,

[image]

---

If data in other sheet is in `Structured References` then

[image]

---

### **Final Edit & Update:**

[image]

---

- `Sheet1` --> is the place where data is stored.
- `Structured References` --> Data is in `Structured References` aka `Tables`
- OP, wants to specifically use <kbd>INDIRECT()</kbd> function.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, INDIRECT(C1),
     φ, DROP(TAKE(α,,1),1),
     δ, DROP(TAKE(α,1),,1),
     Ω, DROP(α,1,1),
     MAP(A2:A3,LAMBDA(m,FILTER(FILTER(Ω,m=φ),m=δ/1))))
```

---

Or,

• in <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, INDIRECT(C1),
     φ, DROP(α,1,1),
     δ, TOROW(IF(φ,DROP(TAKE(α,1),,1)))/1,
     Ω, TOROW(IF(φ,DROP(TAKE(α,,1),1))),
     MMULT((δ=A2:A3)*(Ω=A2:A3),TOCOL(φ)))
```

---

**Notes:** And since the headers are numbers while in `Structured References` it converts to Text format therefore it was divided by `1` to make it numerical --> `δ/1`

---

All solutions posted above can be found here: **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckEZC5oZWIsdMecFz?e=S22LXe)**

---

[image]

---

Comment: This formula: =XLOOKUP(H2,$B$1:$F$1,FILTER($B$2:$F$6,H2=$A$2:$A$6))
and the other formulas don't seem to work if the matrix is stored in another sheet and we are using indirect function to read it.

Comment: @vp_050 sorry see it is not mentioned in your post, i tried to provide all the possibilities. Its no where mentioned in your post that you are using `INDIRECT()` function to read in other sheets.

Comment: I agree and apologize for that. I have now made a note in the question

Comment: @vp_050 i just tried this way and it worked can yu confirm? `=FILTER(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"B2:F6"),INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"A2:A6")=A2),INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"B1:F1")=A2)` and even this is working `=INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"B2:F6"),MATCH(A2,INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"A2:A6"),0),MATCH(A2,INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"B1:F1"),0))`

Comment: @vp_050 do you want to retrieve the values of the various sheets individually or the sum of all of them? In the latter case you may not need INDIRECT.

Comment: I am receiving a CALC! error for the recent formulas. I am not sure why could it be because the matrix is stored as a table format in excel?

Comment: @vp_050 certainly yes!

Comment: Okay. How do we work around this then?

Comment: Could you please post atleast one example? Can we not modify the formula in any way to take care of this?

Comment: @vp_050 posted!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255804/discussion-between-vp-050-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Comment: @vp_050 I am not going to chat since in your second last post also you asked me to join, but you were not there. So i have avoided, thanks, if anything else you would like to ask, i will try.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya what modifications can be done to this formula if rowid and columnid are not equal and given as inputs in two different columns?

Comment: @vp_050 I have updated the worksheet you can refer, also check this **[screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/hogegTD)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The code worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Look Here in this **[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/slDwo1f)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya could you please help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77699495/excel-sort-in-ascending-order-excluding-diagonal-elements

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya could you please help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77699495/excel-sort-in-ascending-order-excluding-diagonal-elements