# Dynamically change the Lookup range/s

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to change the below formula to automatically change the lookup table based on the value in column `work week`

I have 3 identical tables (Week1, Week2, Week3)

```
=INDEX(Week1[[Mon]:[Sun]],MATCH(CLS[@CLS],Week1[Agent],0),MATCH(CLS[@Day],Week1[[#Headers],[Mon]:[Sun]],0))
```

I want to change the look-up table based on what week work week is in the work week column.

I have attempted to change this myself but I keep getting `#VALUE!`. My attempt is below.

```
=INDEX(CLS[@[Work Week]]&"[[Mon]:[Sun]]",MATCH(CLS[@CLS],CLS[@[Work Week]]&"[Agent]",0),MATCH(CLS[@Day],CLS[@[Work Week]]&"[[#Headers],[Mon]:[Sun]]",0)).
```

My other thought was to use Indirect but I couldn't get my head around it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The headings in the table are actual dates formatted as _ddd_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't *think* `CHOOSE` is volatile, so should be better than using `INDIRECT`.

I've removed date formatting to show the values used in the table headers, and used sequential numbers rather than hours to make it easier to see what figure is being returned.

```
=INDEX(
    CHOOSE(SUBSTITUTE([@[Work Week]], "Week", ""), Week1[#All], Week2[#All], Week3[#All]),
    MATCH(
        [@CLS],
        INDEX(CHOOSE(SUBSTITUTE([@[Work Week]], "Week", ""), Week1[#All], Week2[#All], Week3[#All]), 0, 1),
        0
    ),
    MATCH(
        TEXT([@Day], "dd-mmm"),
        INDEX(CHOOSE(SUBSTITUTE([@[Work Week]], "Week", ""), Week1[#All], Week2[#All], Week3[#All]), 1, 0),
        0
    )
)
```

**Table:**  With *Week* removed from the *Work Week* column I can use `CHOOSE` to select the correct table.
**Row:**  I then use `INDEX(<Table>,1,0)` to return the first column and `MATCH` to find the location of the *Agent*.
**Column:** Next I use `INDEX(<Table>,0,1)` to return the first row and `MATCH` to find the date - the headers in the table are treated as text, so the I use `TEXT` to convert the date to text in the correct format.
Finally I use `INDEX(<Table>, <Row>, <Column>` to return the correct cell.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I wasn't sure - could be dates formatted as _ddd_.  It'll work either way, but if the days are just text then can remove the `TEXT([@Day],"dd-mmm")` bits and just use `[@Day]` instead.  Saying that.... for dates shown as in OP then should just use `TEXT([@Day],"ddd")`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you would need a formula like as shown below, although i am not a big fan of `INDIRECT()` function, however, since you want to use the `INDIRECT()` function to make it dynamic then you could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>O3</kbd>

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT([@[Work Week]]&"[#All]"),
  MATCH([@CLS],INDEX(INDIRECT([@[Work Week]]&"[#All]"),,1),0),
  MATCH([@Day],INDEX(INDIRECT([@[Work Week]]&"[#All]"),1,),0))
```

---

With `MS365`

```
=LET(
     _source, INDIRECT([@[Work Week]]&"[#All]"),
     _cls, DROP(_source,1,-7),
     _day, TAKE(_source,1,-7),
     XLOOKUP([@CLS],_cls, FILTER(DROP(_source,1,1),[@Day]=_day)))
```

---

I have made few changes to the original source data as in OP to show the formula does works. if applied the way i have shown. Refer Agent `AH` --> Weeks `1`, `2`,`3` days `Mon`, `Tue` & `Weds`

`Week1` Table:

[image]

---

`Week2` Table:

[image]

---

`Week3` Table:

[image]

---

[image]

---

**Note:** Also the idea is here to refer the `Structured Reference` as a whole i.e. using `[#All]` posted a similar answer using `Structured References` can refer here as well : **[Extract values stored in diagonal elements with the rowid as an input in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396522/extract-values-stored-in-diagonal-elements-with-the-rowid-as-an-input-in-excel)**

---

Alternative Approach, less verbose and would work more faster, using <kbd>VLOOKUP()</kbd>, <kbd>SWITCH()</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH()</kbd> -- Non Volatile!.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>O3</kbd>

```
=VLOOKUP([@CLS],
  SWITCH([@[Work Week]],"Week1",Week1,"Week2",Week2,"Week3",Week3,Week4),
  MATCH([@Day],Week1[#Headers],0),0)
```

---

Since the top headers will be same for all the tables hence we can use one of the table headers as a reference for `Day`.

---

Comment: Thank you very much this will be very useful information going forward

Comment: @PeterMogford posted an alternative non volatile approach using `VLOOKUP()` & `SWITCH()` function, you may like to try as well!