# Excel sort in ascending order excluding diagonal elements

Tags: excel, sorting, matrix, excel-formula, diagonal

The formula below returns the least 10 values if  including the diagonal values if $C$5="Y". How can we only get non-diagonal values if $C$5="Y".

```
=VSTACK({"V1","V2","V3","V4"},
    HSTACK({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10},TAKE(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&
    TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(ABS(IF(ISREF(IF($C$5="N",INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"),IF(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"))=COLUMN(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5")),0,INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5")))), IF($C$5="N",INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"),IF(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"))=COLUMN(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5")),0,INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"))), 0)-
    IF($C$5="N",INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5"),IF(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5"))=COLUMN(INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5")),0,INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5"))))),ABS(IF(ISREF(IF($C$5="N",INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"),IF(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"))=COLUMN(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5")),0,INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5")))), IF($C$5="N",INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"),IF(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"))=COLUMN(INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5")),0,INDIRECT("'"&$C$10&"'!B2:E5"))), 0)-IF($C$5="N",INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5"),IF(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5"))=COLUMN(INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5")),0,INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B2:E5"))))&"|"&INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!A2:A5")&"|"&INDIRECT("'"&$C$9&"'!B1:E1")),3),"|",{1,2,3}),"|"),,1),10)))
```

Sheet 2

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 83 | 37 | 69 | 80 | 52 |
| 2 | 89 | 44 | 30 | 64 | 47 |
| 3 | 56 | 39 | 87 | 88 | 92 |
| 4 | 60 | 38 | 34 | 35 | 93 |
| 5 | 21 | 75 | 66 | 47 | 79 |

Sheet 3

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 22 | 46 | 2 | 27 |
| 2 | 5 | 21 | 37 | 1 | 37 |
| 3 | 11 | 18 | 6 | 32 | 2 |
| 4 | 42 | 10 | 10 | 36 | 46 |
| 5 | 9 | 22 | 1 | 41 | 37 |

Resulting Output:

[image]

Desired output:

The first four rows are diagonal values and should not be there and this table should start from row 5.

Comment: I get this feeling you're not explaining the whole. If we check for the smallest 10, we'd get the 1 first, not 30. Please explain yourself better of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The formula estimates smallest for sheet2-sheet3

Comment: The result you show shows something completely different.
`=LET(r,ROWS(Sheet2!A1:E5),n,NOT(CHOOSEROWS(MUNIT(r),-SEQUENCE(r))+MUNIT(r)),TAKE(SORT(TOCOL(HSTACK(IFS(n,Sheet2!A1:E5),IFS(n,Sheet3!A1:E5)),2)),10))` is the smallest 10 excluding the diagonals.

Comment: @P.b can you suggest a small modification to the formula posted? Also the values are sheet2-sheet3

Comment: @P.b can you post an answer using this formula but for values sheet 2- sheet3?

Comment: I think the question needs updated then. It doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Smallest Differences Between Two Matrices

[image]

```
=LET(r_address,"B2:E5",sample,10,s_ref1,C9,s_ref2,C10,yes_no,C5,
    data1,INDIRECT("'"&s_ref1&"'!"&r_address),
    data2,INDIRECT("'"&s_ref2&"'!"&r_address),
    rc,ROWS(data1),
    s,SEQUENCE(rc^2),
    h,"V"&SEQUENCE(,rc),
    rs,ROUNDUP(s/rc,),
    cs,MOD(s-1,rc)+1,
    d,TOCOL(ABS(data1-data2)),
    st,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(d,rs,cs)),sample),
    f,IF(yes_no="y",FILTER(st,INDEX(st,,2)<>INDEX(st,,3)),st),
VSTACK(h,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(f)),f)))
```

[image]